# Change Google Map size iOS Swift

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift

I can't find anything on this so I am asking. when I use the code provided by Google on its website, I get a map in the controller that is full screen. I want to be able to show it within a container (fixed width & height).

I am using swift and would appreciate your help. Below is the code I extracted from google:

```
Override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86,
            longitude: 151.20, zoom: 2)
        var mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
        self.view = mapView

        var marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20)
        marker.title = "Sydney"
        marker.snippet = "Australia"
        marker.map = mapView

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

Comment: Use a CGRectMake with the width and height of the container in which you want the map go be shown instead of the GcRectZero

Comment: @milo526 that doesnt help if he is assigning the map to specific view, it will always stretch to size of this view, thats why it works with CGRectZero

Answer (score 2):

Your map is going to be as big as the view you are using. You have 2 options.

- 1
  Create subview of specific size and use that view for your GMSMapView, same way you do.
- 2
  Instead of assigning your GMSMapView to some view use

  ```
  view.insertSubview(mapView, atIndex:0)
  ```

  Remember that you have to create a frame for your GMSMapView in this case

  ```
  var mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectMake(...))
  ```

  Good thing about this is you can add other components above your map if you want to(some buttons, labels, etc.), thats not possible with first approach.

#### EDIT

This is the way I do it using autolayout. I created some view in storyboard, gave it constraints so it would resize according to screen size.
Then I initialize my map view and use size of my autoresizing view and insert my mapView to this view.

```
mapView_ = [[GMSMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.viewForMap.bounds];
mapView_.delegate = self;
mapView_.camera = camera;
[self.viewForMap insertSubview:mapView_ atIndex:0];
```

Yes I know this is Objective-C, but this is just an example.

Comment: Nothing changed when i passed CGRectMake(30,30,30,30). Am I missing something?

Comment: @ksa_coder yes instead of `self.view=mapView` you need to use `self.view.insertSubview(mapView, atIndex:0)`

Comment: Thanks @IxPaka. Been looking for this solution for about an hour.

Comment: [go to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40064779/google-maps-gmsmapview-on-custom-uiview)