# Change Google Map Size Programmatically (Swift)

Tags: swift, google-maps, gmsmapview

I am trying to add a Google GMSMapView programmatically but got stuck and would appreciate any help.  I want to set the constraints of the Map to the edges of the view.

However, when I do this I get an error of, "Unable to activate constraint with anchors  and  because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?"

```
var mapView:GMSMapView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200), camera: GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 51.050657, longitude: 10.649514, zoom: 5.5))

    mapView?.center = self.view.center

    mapView?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive=true
    mapView?.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive=true
    mapView?.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive=true
    mapView?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 60).isActive=true

    self.view.addSubview(mapView!)

}
```

I can get Google Maps to load properly if leave out the anchors, so I believe I have it set up properly otherwise.  I just don't understand the concept of how to set the anchors properly.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29162063/change-google-map-size-ios-swift) is similar but is focused more on adding the View with auto layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue occurs when you apply constraints to a view before adding it the to parent view. Also set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false to make the constraints work.

```
self.view.addSubview(mapView!)
mapView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
mapView?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive=true
mapView?.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive=true
mapView?.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive=true
mapView?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 60).isActive=true
```

Comment: Ah!  So simple, yet so far away to what I was thinking.  Thank you!